# How can I prevent white spaces, empty values, and invalid dates in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**USERS table**

```
CREATE TABLE `USERS` (
 `ID` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `NAME` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `EMAIL` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `CREATED_IN` datetime NOT NULL,
 `SIGNED_IN` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

**The trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER `ABC` BEFORE INSERT ON `USERS` FOR EACH ROW 
IF NEW.ID = "" OR NEW.NAME = "" OR 
NEW.CREATED_IN = "" OR NEW.CREATED_IN = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" OR 
NEW.SIGNED_IN = "" OR NEW.SIGNED_IN = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" 
THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE "45000"; END IF
```

**ID column**

- How can I make it doesn't accept empty values? `("", " ", "  ", "   ", etc...) -> Should return an error`
- If there was a value already, How can I remove all spaces from it? `("bf9 d  34 c9 08" = "bf9d34c908")`

**NAME column**

- How can I make it doesn't accept empty values? `("", " ", "  ", "   ", etc...) -> Should return an error`

**EMAIL column**

- How can I make it doesn't accept empty values? `("", " ", "  ", "   ", etc...) -> Should return an error`
- If there was a value already, How can I remove all spaces from it? `("nkr owks lpehqp jmgdb @     gm ail. com" = "nkrowkslpehqpjmgdb@gmail.com")`

**CREATED_IN and SIGNED_IN columns**

- How can I make it doesn't accept invalid values? When inserting invalid values like letters, numbers, or invalid format then should return an error instead of putting 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

> MySQL version is 5.7

What is the best way to handle these requirements on the USERS table?

Comment: Create BEFORE INSERT trigger which performs needed checkings and transformations and performs SIGNAL statement if some parameter is not valid one.

Comment: @Akina Yes, I already did that and that worked but there is a bug. If I executed this command `INSERT INTO USERS (ID) VALUES ('56')` That will respect ID rules but other columns will be empty, I was expected that will reject the insert.

Comment: You must check ALL conditions in your trigger and generate `SIGNAL` if ANY condition is not met.

Comment: *EMAIL column: - If there was a value already, How can I remove all spaces from it?* email address can contain spaces. For example, `"This is my e-mail"@myhost.com` is valid email address.

Comment: @Akina I deleted the trigger because that was not working, I'll rewrite it and share it with you. Give me 15 - 20 minutes please.

Comment: Add it to the question text.

Comment: If it is possible - you should consider switching to PostgreSQL where you can define CHECK constraints for the table and apply regular expression rules.

Comment: @Akina Check the update, That trigger doesn't handle remove spaces. Does the trigger looks good?

Comment: If you are on mySQL v8.0.16 or above, you can use CHECK constraints on the table or column to implement this.  Prior to that, CHECK constraints could be defined but not enforced.  See docs at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trigger can look like this:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER process_input
BEFORE INSERT ON USERS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.id = REPLACE(NEW.id, ' ', '');
    IF NEW.id = '' THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = '`id` cannot be empty.';
    END IF;

    SET NEW.name = TRIM(NEW.name);
    IF NEW.name = '' THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = '`name` cannot be empty.';
    END IF;

    SET NEW.email = REPLACE(NEW.email, ' ', '');
    IF NEW.email = '' THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = '`email` cannot be empty.';
    END IF;

    IF STR_TO_DATE(created_in, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') IS NULL THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Incorrect `created_in` datetime value.';
    END IF;

    IF STR_TO_DATE(signed_in, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') IS NULL THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Incorrect `signed_in` datetime value.';
    END IF;
END
```

Pay attention - this trigger allows NULL in any value (but only email can be NULL, all another columns are defined as NOT NULL).

You may resort the blocks and put the conditions with the most probability first. The trigger does not execute the below code after SIGNAL is executed.

Comment: `SET NEW.id = REPLACE(NEW.id, ' ', '');` What if was there is more than one of white space? 10 20 50

Comment: @T38416 Why you haven't look at the function description in the Reference Manual? The function replaces all occurences.

Comment: I'm trying to remove new lines also but these commands does not work, Do you know why? `SET NEW.ID = REPLACE(NEW.ID, "\\n", "");` `SET NEW.ID = REPLACE(NEW.ID, "\n", "");`

Comment: The second SET is correct until the linebreak is `\n` (Unix style) and not `\r\n` (Windows style).